# Get current session in spring boot application that utilize spring-session backed by MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-session

I have an instance of `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` that intercept request to check locale...

```
public class LocaleControllerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {   
             @Override
             public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
                   final HttpSession session = SessionContextHolder.getSession();
                   // ...
             } 
}
```

and my `SessionContextHolder` is :

```
public abstract class SessionContextHolder {

        public static HttpSession getSession() {
            ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
            return attr.getRequest().getSession(true);
        }

}
```

when I want to call an endpoint, the preHandle() method of the interceptor will called 2 times (why?!), in the first call, the session that `SessionContextHolder` gives me (by `getSession()` method) is an instance of `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade`, and the second time is an instance of `org.springframework.session.data.mongo.MongoExpiringSession`.
I've already enabled MongoHttpSession by `@EnableMongoHttpSession` annotation.
The problem is that, I expect that the session should always be an instance of `MongoExpiringSession` but is not.

Can anyone explain the mechanism of Spring-Session and the reason of this behavior?

Comment: That's strange; I don't think it should be being called twice. Spring Session works by using a standard servlet filter to replace the session in the request context.

Comment: Also why aren't you simply using `request.getSession`? Way make it more complex then that and use the contraption you have in place.

Comment: Thank you @chrylis for your comment. I've wondered too. I test it for several time, and it always called twice. But this codes is part of a big project with more than 50k lines of code with several interceptors,I think I should check another part of project to find the reason!

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. You're right. But I used `SessionContextHolder` in a context which has not the request itself (e.g. for set the default locale). I wrote this code instead of passing request...

Comment: Which might be a bad idea, as that ties the whole codebase to the web layer. Also do you really need it? Spring already has the `LocaleContextHolder` to obtain the current `Locale` and it integrates with the `LocaleResolver`, it feels a bit like you are trying to bolt your own on top of something that already is supported (more easily) by spring.

Comment: Dear @M.Deinum, my reason to use this approach is that I need to store the locale during the session life, but as far as I know, `LocalContecxtHolder` utilizes `ThreadLocal` to store current `Locale` that means need to send the expected locale with each request. In my way, I store the current locale as a session attribute, so it's alive during the session life.

Comment: The `LocaleContextHolder` indeed uses a `ThreadLocal` however your understanding is wrong. The `ThreadLocal` is filled based on the value retrieved from the `LocaleResolver` for the duration of the current request. Now the coincidence is that there is a `SessionLocaleResolver` which does basically what you are trying to achieve yourself (again). That combined with the `DispatcherServlet` does all you need.